# Find all $b\in \mathbb R$, when $x\lt 1$ then $\frac{b^2+bx-b}{b^2-b+x-1}\gt 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all $b\in \mathbb R$, such that if  $x\lt 1$ then:
$$\frac{b^2+bx-b}{b^2-b+x-1}\gt 0$$

Comment: Is the solution $b>1-x$

Comment: It is highly recommended to show some effort. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints.

I assume that you mean to find the value of $b$ such that $$\frac{b^2+bx-b}{b^2-b+x-1}>0 \Leftrightarrow x<1$$

Note that $$\frac{b^2+bx-b}{b^2-b+x-1}>0 \Leftrightarrow(b^2+bx-b)(b^2-b+x-1)>0 $$

If $b<0$, this implies that $(x+b-1)(x+b^2-b-1)<0$.

Note that $1-b >1+b-b^2 \Leftrightarrow b^2-2b>0$ which is true if $b<0$.

This implies that $1-b>x>1+b-b^2$ satisfies the inequality.

However, note that if $1+b-b^2>x$ then  $\frac{b^2+bx-b}{b^2-b+x-1}<0$. This implies there exists such $x<1$ that does not satisfy the inequality. Contradiction!

If $b=0$, then the $(LHS)$ is $0$, implying that $0>0$. Contradiction!

I think that you can solve the case when $b>0$ from here.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{hint:}$
$$
\frac{b^2 +bx-b}{b^2-b+x-1} = \frac{b^2-b +(x-1)-(x-1)+bx}{b^2-b+x-1}=1+\frac{x(b-1)+1}{b^2-b+x-1}>0
$$
rearrange we have
$$
\frac{x(b-1)+1}{b^2-b+x-1} > -1
$$